# UIImageview load from maindelegate

Tags: ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

I try to load an uiimageview from the maindelegate so i can assign it later in each view that loads...but when i assign the local variable to the maindelegate variable the image does not show up! The image loads correctly when i initialize the uiimageview inside the view and not from maindelegate!

i have added the below code in the viewdidappear,viewdidload,viewwillappear etc
**imageview1.image=maindelegate.imageview2.image** 
nothing happens

when i put this code
**uiimage *image1;
imageview1.image=image1; 
it works**

but i want to load it from the maindelegate when the app starts! does anyone experience the same problem? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgotten to initialize it correctly!